# Change color of plotly label

Tags: python, plotly, sankey-diagram

So I have a pretty basic Sankey plot pretty similar to the one in the documentation:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A1, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
      value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2]
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

[image]

What I want to do is to change the color of the label (A1,A2..).
How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [reference documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/sankey/) carefully :)

```
fig.update_traces(textfont_color=<VALUE>, selector=dict(type='sankey'))
```

this should set the fontcolor of your node labels

Comment: Thanks for this and the documentation link. Also is there any way to change or remove the background color that we have just around the text in the plot above?

Comment: @Tarique , I haven't found any mention of this "text shade" in the documentation (but don't trust me, check yourself). My guess is that it depends on the _**plot_bgcolor**_ as in [this example](https://plotly.com/python/sankey-diagram/#style-sankey-diagram)

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. I couldn't find anything that did in the documentation

Comment: Theoretically, you can get around that with annotations, since you control every aspect of its text and box. But manually substituting every label with corresponding annotation is a hell of a work. Try asking the same question on [plotly forum](https://community.plotly.com)

Comment: Also, I was wrong: it is **paper_bgcolor** that controls the shade of node labels